# Unable to post tag returned through document.getElementById('div').innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am working on this form with several select elements with options Yes, No or Not applicable. It was required that whenever the user select yes option a separate date field appears next to it. I used HTML DOM document.getElementById("id").innerHTML for this date field. Everything went well but I was not able to pass the value of date to the form action page using POST method. Check this code:

```
    <!-- javascript code -->  
  <script type="text/javascript">

function credit_check(name){
  if(name=='YES')document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='Date: <input type="date" name="credit_check_date" value= "mm/dd/yyyy" />';
  else document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='';
}
function employment_check(name){
  if(name=='YES')document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML='Date: <input type="date" name="employment_check_date" value= "mm/dd/yyyy" />';
  else document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML='';
}

</script>



</head>

<body>
<?php include("menu.inc"); ?>  
  <div id="main">

 <table>
<form method="post" action="checkinfo.php">  
       <tr><td colspan=2><hr/><input type="hidden" name="consultant_id" value="<?php echo $consult_id; ?>"> </td>

       </tr>

    <tr align="center">
    <td><b>Credit Check </b></td>
    <td>  
            <select name="2" onchange="credit_check(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
                <option value="YES">Yes</option>
                <option value="NO">No</option>
                <option value="NA">Not Applicable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <div id ="div2"> </div></td>
  </tr>

 <tr align="center">
    <td><b>Employment Check :<font color='red'>*</font></b></td>
    <td>  
            <select name="3" onchange="employment_check(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
                <option value="YES">Yes</option>
                <option value="NO">No</option>
                <option value="NA">Not Applicable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <div id ="div3"> </div></td>
    </tr>

    </form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the inputs into the HTML at loading, then simply hide/show them.

```
    <!-- javascript code -->  
  <script type="text/javascript">

function credit_check(name){
  if(name=='YES')document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
  else document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
}
function employment_check(name){
  if(name=='YES')document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'block';
  else document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none';
}

</script>



</head>

<body>
<?php include("menu.inc"); ?>  
  <div id="main">

 <table>
<form method="post" action="checkinfo.php">  
       <tr><td colspan=2><hr/><input type="hidden" name="consultant_id" value="<?php echo $consult_id; ?>"> </td>

       </tr>

    <tr align="center">
    <td><b>Credit Check </b></td>
    <td>  
            <select name="2" onchange="credit_check(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
                <option value="YES">Yes</option>
                <option value="NO">No</option>
                <option value="NA">Not Applicable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <div id ="div2" style="display: none;"> 
            Date: <input type="date" name="credit_check_date" value= "mm/dd/yyyy" />
        </div></td>
  </tr>

 <tr align="center">
    <td><b>Employment Check :<font color='red'>*</font></b></td>
    <td>  
            <select name="3" onchange="employment_check(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
                <option value="YES">Yes</option>
                <option value="NO">No</option>
                <option value="NA">Not Applicable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> <div id ="div3" style="display: none;"> 
            Date: <input type="date" name="employment_check_date" value= "mm/dd/yyyy" />
        </div></td>
    </tr>

    </form>
</table>
```

It's also a good idea to check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it makes this kind of stuff a lot easier to do.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo -](http://jsfiddle.net/L45gyrux/1)** Change `function credit_check(name)` to  `window.credit_check = function(name)`

```
window.credit_check = function(name){
    if(name=='YES') document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='Date: <input type="date" name="credit_check_date" value= "mm/dd/yyyy" />';
    else document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='';
}

window.employment_check = function (name){
    if(name=='YES') document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML='Date: <input type="date" name="employment_check_date" value= "mm/dd/yyyy" />';
    else document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML='';
}
```

You're script wasn't loading properly,

`Uncaught ReferenceError: credit_check is not defined`  in your console shows the error. The functions were not being defined. You can set your functions like above or reposition your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already working. See http://jsfiddle.net/2wg4u6ut/

Make sure your JavaScript is in the head section of your document.
There were some minor issues in your formatting where the `<form>` tag belongs around the table.

You also were missing the submit button, but then it's already working.

Comment: Sorry, I might have removed the submit button mistakenly while removing the extra code. The code works just fine.But I'm not able to POST the date entered by the user, on checkinfo.php.